# Optional value error after updating to Xcode 6 GM

Tags: swift

I have just updated to Xcode 6 GM and I am fixing some issues that have appeared. Most things are now working however I have encountered an error that I am unsure about how to rectify.

I have this code in vieDidLoad():

```
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    currencyFormatter.currencyCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol, value: NSLocaleCurrencyCode)!
```

I get an error on the second line.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I'm sure the solution is simple but I'm pretty new to programming so I haven't been able to find a fix.

Comment: When you use explicit unwrapping you are guaranteeing that the result will never be nil. Instead do not use explicit unwrapping and test for nil and use an `if` to avoid the nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong method to get the currency code. That wouldn't be a problem, the method just returns `nil` because it couldn't find the value. But you explicitly unwrapped the optional by adding the `!`, that should be avoided.

I would suggest the following code:

```
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle

let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
if let currencyCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String {
    currencyFormatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
}
```

This only sets the currency code if it was returned by the `objectForKey` method. As POB pointed out correctly in the comments below, `objectForKey` returns a `AnyObject?`. In this case it's safe to add `as? String`, which casts it to a `String?`.

Comment: Your code will generate a warning and an error message with Xcode 6 GM. In order to fix it, you should change your second line to: `if let currencyCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String {`.

Answer (score 2):

`currencyCode` property of `currencyFormatter` is of type `String`. When you want to set it to the current locale currency code of your device, you have to use the following code:

```
let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
currencyFormatter.currencyCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as String
println(currencyFormatter.currencyCode) //Will display "USD", for example
```

However, as Guido Hendriks pointed out, `objectForKey:` returns `AnyObject?`. *The Swift Programming Language* recommends to use optional binding in order to unwrap safely optionals. Therefore, your code should look like the following:

```
let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
if let currencyCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String {
    currencyFormatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
    println(currencyFormatter.currencyCode) //Will display "USD", for example
}
```

Comment: This way you downcast an `AnyObject?` to a `String`, which also unwraps the optional. Will crash the app if it's `nil`.

Comment: @Guido Hendriks: Updated. Thanks.